# Using REST API to get list items from Sharepoint [site content] in React and displaying it in table format

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, spfx, modern-experience, react

I am trying below code to fetch list items from SharePoint and displaying in table format using REST API up to some point I have wrote the below code.
I am unable to figure out how the items will be fetched or how to select columns from list items to display it in table (Suppose I do have Name, Email, Phone and ID on list items):

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: `${this.props.siteUrl}/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('App_Name')/items`, 
       type: "GET", 
       headers:{'Accept': 'application/json; odata=verbose;'}, 
       success: function(resultData) {          
         reactHandler.setState({ 
           items: resultData.d.results 
         }); 
       }, 
       error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
       } 
   });
```

For displaying it in table format I am using react-table-component which has rows and columns value in it.

Comment: What I am trying to do how to put values in rows and columns property of react-data-table-component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$select` in SharePoint REST API to select particular columns from SharePoint list. You need to use **internal name** of column in REST API. You can get the internal name of your columns by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

You can use REST endpoint like:

```
/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('App_Name')/items?$select=ID,Title,Name,Email,Phone
```

Comment: No, not like that I mean I have to represent it in a table format and for that I am using react-data-table-component. In that there are properties rows and columns so how to put the Sharepoint items in rows and columns of react-data-table

Answer (score 1):

@Dhanjay Bhardwaj,

If you're developing an SPFx React app (webpart or extension), I suggest you use [SPHttpClient](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/connect-to-sharepoint#retrieve-lists-from-sharepoint-site) or [PnPJS](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/items/#get) to fetch items from SharePoint list.

Compare to `$.ajax`, the above helper classes execute REST API requests against SharePoint. It adds default headers, manages the digest needed for writes.

You can have a look below tutorials:

- https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/displaying-data-into-reactbootstraptablenext
  https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-work-with-list-items-in-spfx-using-rest-api-retrieve-list-data-part-o/

Comment: If I change from ajax to SP now I have to change it in all of my files. cause using different methods in different file will take time to understand the code